# Отправка сообщения по нажатию кнопки PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, tcp-ip

я новичок, подскажите как мне переделать код сервера, что бы он отправлял сообщение клиенту по нажатию на кнопки.
Код сервера:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QByteArray, QDataStream, QIODevice
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QHostAddress, QTcpServer

class Server(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.tcpServer = None
        self.button = QPushButton("Click", self)
        self.button.move(50, 50)

    def sessionOpened(self):
        self.tcpServer = QTcpServer(self)
        PORT = 8000
        address = QHostAddress('127.0.0.1')
        if not self.tcpServer.listen(address, PORT):
            print("cant listen!")
            self.close()
            return
        self.tcpServer.newConnection.connect(self.dealCommunication)

    def dealCommunication(self):
        clientConnection = self.tcpServer.nextPendingConnection()
        block = QByteArray()
        out = QDataStream(block, QIODevice.WriteOnly)
        out.writeUInt16(0)
        message = "sdfsdfsdf4terg3grgjggy"
        message = bytes(message, encoding='ascii')
        out.writeString(message)
        out.device().seek(0)
        out.writeUInt16(block.size() - 2)
        clientConnection.disconnected.connect(clientConnection.deleteLater)
        clientConnection.write(block)
        clientConnection.disconnectFromHost()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    server = Server()
    server.button.clicked.connect(server.sessionOpened)

    sys.exit(server.exec_())
```

Код клиента:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDataStream, QIODevice
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QTcpSocket, QAbstractSocket

class Client(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.tcpSocket = QTcpSocket(self)
        self.blockSize = 0
        self.makeRequest()
        self.tcpSocket.waitForConnected(1000)
        self.tcpSocket.readyRead.connect(self.dealCommunication)
        self.tcpSocket.error.connect(self.displayError)

    def makeRequest(self):
        HOST = '127.0.0.1'
        PORT = 8000
        self.tcpSocket.connectToHost(HOST, PORT)

    def dealCommunication(self):
        instr = QDataStream(self.tcpSocket)
        #instr.setVersion(QDataStream.Qt_5_0)
        if self.blockSize == 0:
            if self.tcpSocket.bytesAvailable() < 2:
                return
            self.blockSize = instr.readUInt16()
        if self.tcpSocket.bytesAvailable() < self.blockSize:
            return
        print(str(instr.readString(), encoding='ascii'))

    def displayError(self, socketError):
        if socketError == QAbstractSocket.RemoteHostClosedError:
            pass
        else:
            print(self, "The following error occurred: %s." % self.tcpSocket.errorString())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    client = Client()
    sys.exit(client.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы зачем-то закрываете соединение сразу после его установления. Вам же надо при установлении соединения запомнить это соединение (`QTcpSocket`) а по нажатию кнопки просто отправлять текст (см. слот для кнопки `sendText`)

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QByteArray, QDataStream, QIODevice
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QPushButton, QInputDialog
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QHostAddress, QTcpServer

class Server(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.tcpServer = None
        self.button = QPushButton("Send", self)
        self.button.move(50, 50)
        self.clientConnection = None
        self.tcpServer = QTcpServer(self)
        PORT = 8000
        address = QHostAddress('127.0.0.1')
        if not self.tcpServer.listen(address, PORT):
            print("cant listen!")
            self.close()
            return
        self.tcpServer.newConnection.connect(self.dealCommunication)
        print("listening for connection\n")


    def sendText(self):
        if not self.clientConnection:
            print("I don't have an active connection\n")
            return
        text, result = QInputDialog.getText(self, "input", "text to send")
        self.clientConnection.write(QByteArray(text.encode()))
        self.clientConnection.write('\n'.encode())


    def dealCommunication(self):
        self.clientConnection = self.tcpServer.nextPendingConnection()
        block = QByteArray()
        out = QDataStream(block, QIODevice.WriteOnly)
        out.writeUInt16(0)
        message = "hi folks!\n"
        message = bytes(message, encoding='ascii')
        out.writeString(message)
        out.device().seek(0)
        out.writeUInt16(block.size() - 2)
        self.clientConnection.disconnected.connect(self.clientConnection.deleteLater)
        self.clientConnection.write(block)
        #self.clientConnection.disconnectFromHost() <--- вот этого не надо

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    server = Server()
    server.button.clicked.connect(server.sendText)

    sys.exit(server.exec_())
```